# Problem compiling json with visual studio

Tags: c++, json

I have another program that uses json but I do not manage to make it compile. I think that the problem is related to the library I am using to parse a Json file, so, I coded a small code to try to understand better how it works.
When I am compiling the program using visual Studio 2019 in Windows the following errors appear (I have translated the errors to english so some inaccuracy may have been introduced ):

```
Error   C4996   'Json::Reader::parse': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.    ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\S510U\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp Line:21
    
Warning C26812  The numeration type "Json::CommentPlacement" has no scope. Prefer "enum class" to "enum" (Enum.3).  ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\packages\JsonCpp.Windows.1.9.2\build\native\include\json\value.h 589 
Warning C26812  The numeration type "Json::ValueType" has no scope. Prefer "enum class" to "enum" (Enum.3). ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\packages\JsonCpp.Windows.1.9.2\build\native\include\json\value.h 618 
Warning C26812  The numeration type "Json::PathArgument::Kind" has no scope. \UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\packages\JsonCpp.Windows.1.9.2\build\native\include\json\value.h    732 
Waring C4275    It has been used an interface not of the DLL class 'std::exception' as a base for the interface DLL class 'Json::Exception' ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\packages\JsonCpp.Windows.1.9.2\build\native\include\json\value.h 57  
Error   C4996   'Json::Reader': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.   ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp  19  
Error   C4996   'Json::Reader::Reader': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead    ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp  19
```

However, when I try to run it in Linux using g++ it works.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <vector>   
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "string.h"
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include "json/json.h"
    using namespace std;
    int main(void){
    string namedir = "fichero.json";
    ifstream ifs(namedir);
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value obj;
    reader.parse(ifs, obj);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, it helps if you provide the error messages and the OS you are using. Then which compiler you are using and so on. Why does it work "in linux"? But not on whatever?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question.

Comment: So where did you put in the library? I guess it is a header only library. Do you know hot the c/c++ compilation and linking works?

Comment: I used NuGet to manage the library. In visual studio json/json.h appears in external dependencies. I am a little bit lost with compiling in visual studio

Comment: Can you provide the error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using an old interface of this library: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp ?

There is this error reported e.g. : https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/815

This is a warning that says you should not use the old interface but instead the newer one. The warning is handled as an error from MSVC (visual studio) because your warning level is set to high. GCC does not throw an error because it lets pass the warning as it is (This is an assumption).

To resolve the warning you need to reduce the warning level in the project properties, but in my eyes this is a bad idea.

Better use the new interface of the library and always have a look at the warnings which the compiler is giving you. It will reduce a lot of headaches you coudl get while ignoring them ;) (like that problem)